# How to make a `FileHandler` strip terminal escape sequences (colors) from a log message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, logging, terminal

I have a single `Logger` with two `Handler`s: `StreamHandler` and `FileHandler`.

I want to log colored output to the terminal using escape sequences (see *Logger usage*) via the `StreamHandler`. However, I don't want to log such escape sequences via the `FileHandler`:

```
Log to StreamHandler: \033[39m{}\033[0m\033[91m{}\033[0m\033[39m{}\033[0m
Log to FileHandler: {}{}{}
```

In order words, the `FileHandler` should strip the terminal escape sequences.

Is there any solution besides creating two `Logger`s configured with a `StreamHandler` and `FileHandler`, respectively?

I really don't want to carry two separate `Logger`s around in the code, if it can be avoided.

**Logger usage**:

```
fmt = 'Match: {} ({}/v{}): \033[39m{}\033[0m\033[91m{}\033[0m\033[39m{}\033[0m ({}) {}'

self.logger.info(
    fmt,
    o.type.lower(),
    o.id,
    o.version,
    remove_control_chars(match.left),
    remove_control_chars(match.text),
    remove_control_chars(match.right),
    match.regex,
    suffix
)
```

**Logger configuration**:

```
def init(log, level, no_console):
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '{asctime:s} -- {levelname:<5s} -- {name:s} -- {process:d} -- {funcName:s} -- {message:s}',
        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
        style='{'
    )

    logger = logging.getLogger('watchdog')

    if getattr(logging, level.upper()) is None:
        raise common.exc.WatchdogException(f'Failed to set level for logger: {level.upper()}')

    logger.setLevel(getattr(logging, level.upper()))

    if not no_console:
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)

    try:
        handler = logging.FileHandler(log, mode='w+')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
    except Exception as exc:
        raise common.exc.WatchdogException(f'Failed to initialize file handler: {log}') from exc
```

Answer (score 1):

[It is possible to strip the extra characters in the `FileHandler` by adding a `Filter` to it](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#filters-contextual) but there is a much better solution. Each handler can have their own `Formatter`. So the ideal way would be to add a `Formatter` only to the `StreamHandler` which adds the terminal escape sequences to the log.

Comment: Thank you. In my case, the log message contains arbitrary text, so it can be hard to know where exactly to put the terminal escapes. Do you have a solution for that? I've taken the decision to remove terminal escapes instead in the `FileHandler`: `record.msg = re.sub('\033\[91m(.*)\033\[0m', '\\1', record.msg)`, but I'm worried if such regex matching would impact the performance of the application, when there are MANY log messages?